# Windows 8 Store App: How to find the visible ListViewItems of a ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-8

I want to find the visible ListViewItems of my listView in a Windows 8 Store App. Is there an easy way to do without iterating through each of them to check their visibility?

What I mean is that I have a ListView that binds to a list of 1000 items. The user swipes through the ListView in the UI, and stops scrolling at a certain item. I would like to know that Item and its UI container to calculate its size.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'visible'? There is no `Hide` property for a `ListViewItem`. Do you mean that you're trying to compare a data binding to another list, or something like that?

Regardless, you can avoid iterating by casting it and using linq if you'd like. You can use any valid property of the `ListViewItem` this way.

For (simple) example: how to select specific items of `ListViewItems` by their text value and get the text associated with them.

```
string[] items = listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Where(s => s.Text == "Apple" || s.Text == "Banana").
                                                      Select(s => s.Text).ToArray();
foreach (string item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Outputs...

```
Apple
Banana
```

Just change the `Where` clauses to match your setup, and the `Select` to whichever property you want to select.